# How to expose trait functions as extern functions in a cdylib?

Tags: rust, ffi

I would like to define a trait named `API` which defines a set of functions that should be exposed to native. I may have several implementations of the API, so the trait makes sure that I won't by mistake miss a function from the set.

I declared the trait and implemented it:

```rust
pub trait API {
    extern "C" fn foo();
}

pub struct MyImpl1;
impl API for MyImpl1 {
    #[no_mangle]
    extern "C" fn foo() {
        println!("foo");
    }
}
```

I compile the crate as a `cdylib` with `cargo build`. The `Cargo.toml` is as below:

```
[package]
name = "api-trait"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

It seems that even when I make `MyImpl1` public, the symbol `foo` does not exist in the generated binary.

On macOS, using `nm target/debug/libapi_trait.dylib`, I got

```
0000000000000f64 s GCC_except_table10
                 U __Unwind_GetDataRelBase
                 U __Unwind_GetIPInfo
                 U __Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData
                 U __Unwind_GetRegionStart
                 U __Unwind_GetTextRelBase
                 U __Unwind_SetGR
                 U __Unwind_SetIP
0000000000000ec0 t __ZN12panic_unwind3imp14find_eh_action28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17h882730ec655d7cb8E
0000000000000ed0 t __ZN12panic_unwind3imp14find_eh_action28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hf5c37156294234d5E
0000000000000a10 t __ZN12panic_unwind5dwarf2eh20read_encoded_pointer17h9109e27fb696b750E
00000000000009e0 t __ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce40call_once$u7b$$u7b$vtable.shim$u7d$$u7d$17h1282dc016f2aa15fE
00000000000009f0 t __ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce40call_once$u7b$$u7b$vtable.shim$u7d$$u7d$17h6c6c5197d1b45824E
0000000000000a00 t __ZN4core3ptr18real_drop_in_place17ha0a3e8a3d7a638afE
0000000000002038 d __dyld_private
0000000000000bd0 T _rust_eh_personality
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

On Linux, using `nm target/debug/libapi_trait.so`, I get

```
0000000000202008 b __bss_start
0000000000202008 b completed.7697
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000710 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000007a0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000201d28 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000202000 d __dso_handle
0000000000201d90 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000202008 d _edata
0000000000202010 b _end
0000000000000ccc t _fini
00000000000007e0 t frame_dummy
0000000000201d20 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000000ecc r __FRAME_END__
0000000000201f90 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000d30 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
00000000000006d8 t _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000000750 t register_tm_clones
00000000000009a0 T rust_eh_personality
0000000000202008 d __TMC_END__
                 U _Unwind_GetDataRelBase@@GCC_3.0
                 U _Unwind_GetIPInfo@@GCC_4.2.0
                 U _Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData@@GCC_3.0
                 U _Unwind_GetRegionStart@@GCC_3.0
                 U _Unwind_GetTextRelBase@@GCC_3.0
                 U _Unwind_SetGR@@GCC_3.0
                 U _Unwind_SetIP@@GCC_3.0
0000000000000cb0 t _ZN12panic_unwind3imp14find_eh_action28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17h7d8572c3ef9c01a4E
0000000000000cc0 t _ZN12panic_unwind3imp14find_eh_action28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17h8f3ed794c49a4682E
0000000000000820 t _ZN12panic_unwind5dwarf2eh20read_encoded_pointer17he5d3453b5c6c588aE
00000000000007f0 t _ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce40call_once$u7b$$u7b$vtable.shim$u7d$$u7d$17h91ae32eaf5f323cfE
0000000000000800 t _ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce40call_once$u7b$$u7b$vtable.shim$u7d$$u7d$17h95ce8da4c283a783E
0000000000000810 t _ZN4core3ptr18real_drop_in_place17h02c8363f4a3e6833E
```

`foo` does not exist in either. What have I missed?

Comment: Your plan *seems* fundamentally flawed, however. If you don't mangle the name, then it's impossible to have multiple implementations of the trait because then you'll get name clashes...

Comment: Yep, that explains the difference. I was using `dylib`, not `cdylib`. Since you provided the `Cargo.toml`, I was able to copy-paste it without making a typo when re-typing it.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah. Using `dylib` would be fine. I feel this is somehow related with this issue I submitted before. https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2771